# Inner join exactly on one column and fuzzy on another

Tags: r, join, dplyr, fuzzy-comparison, exact-match

I have two dataframes I want to join. They share two fields: `group_id` and `person_name`. I want to join exactly on `group_id` and fuzzy on `person_name`. How can I do this?

Constraints:

- It should be an inner join. So `group_id` exactly and `person_name` fuzzy must appear in both the left and right frames.
- The real dataframes are large. I have tried [the answer suggested by David Robinson using his package fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin/issues/18), but there is too much data to create a Cartesian product before filtering.
- I'd love an answer in the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/) but it's not strictly necessary.

Here is a small example:

```
a = data.frame(
    group_id=c(1,2,2,3,3,3),
    person_name=c('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve', 'Frank'),
    eye_color=c('brown', 'green', 'blue', 'brown', 'green', 'blue')
)
b = data.frame(
    group_id=c(2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    person_name=c('Alie', 'Bobo', 'Charles', 'Charlie', 'Davis', 'Eva', 'Zed' ),
    hair_color=c('brown', 'brown', 'black', 'grey', 'brown', 'black', 'blond')
)
expected = data.frame(
    group_id=c(2,2,3,3),
    person_name_x=c('Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve'),
    person_name_y=c('Bobo', 'Charles', 'Davis', 'Eva'),
    eye_color=c('green', 'blue', 'brown', 'green'),
    hair_color=c('brown', 'black', 'brown', 'black')
)
```

Comment: You might want to check out the packages `RecordLinkage` (see answer) or [`fastLink`](https://github.com/kosukeimai/fastLink), which allow blocking and fuzzy matching.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
library(RecordLinkage)
library(tidyverse)
compare.linkage(a, b, strcmp = 2, exclude=3, blockfld = 1) %>% 
  epiWeights %>% 
  epiClassify(.8) %>% 
  getPairs(show="links", single.rows=T) %>% 
  .[(c(2,3,7,4,8))]
# group_id.1 person_name.1 person_name.2 eye_color.1 hair_color.2
# 3          2       Charlie       Charles        blue        black
# 2          2           Bob          Bobo       green        brown
# 4          3         David         Davis       brown        brown
# 5          3           Eve           Eva       green        black
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, we basically need a hybrid join. For one column (`group_id`), we need an exact match of column names whereas for the other column (`person_name`) we need a fuzzy join.

One way to do this :

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
common_id <- intersect(a$group_id, b$group_id)
stringdist_inner_join(a[a$group_id %in% common_id, ], b[b$group_id %in% common_id, ], 
                                                      by = "person_name")

# group_id.x person_name.x eye_color group_id.y person_name.y hair_color
#        <dbl>        <fctr>    <fctr>      <dbl>        <fctr>     <fctr>
#1          2           Bob     green          2          Bobo      Brown
#2          2       Charlie      blue          2       Charles      Black
#3          3         David     brown          3         Davis      Brown
#4          3           Eve     green          3           Eva      Black
```

Here, we first find those common `group_id`'s using `intersect` which are present in both the dataframes and filter them accordingly from `a` and `b` and then use `stringdist_inner_join` function on only `person_name` column. We can later remove the extra `group_id` column which has been generated.

Comment: This does not check the exact match on `group_id`. I edited my test case to demonstrate. Doing this and then filtering afterwards takes too much memory.

Comment: @Hatshepsut so you tried `df <- stringdist_inner_join(a, b, by = "person_name"); df[df$group_id.x == df$group_id.y, ]` right?